# Meaning of macro foo(a,b, ;)

Tags: c, macros

I was going through some old C code at my company, which is compiled without the `gcc -flags` option, and I came across a strange line of code.

```
#define foo(a,b) foonew(a,b, ;)
```

Can anyone explain to me what this does?

EDIT :
Because it is part of a large code base which is not compiled with `gcc -flags`, I cannot see if pre-processed `form.Compilation` completes successfully without errors or warnings.

Comment: What is `foonew`? Is it another macro? (Regardless, this is very odd)

Comment: Can you show a use case?

Comment: It depends on the using occurrences. The best way is to examine the preprocessed form of the entire compilation unit (e.g. with `gcc -C -E` on Linux). Macros can do many textual operations, and some people write weird macros.

Comment: I cannot access foonew , so I cannot tell if its macro or function call

Comment: _Why_ can't it be compiled? What's the error message? How can't you access `foonew`? It must appear somewhere in the code, so are you saying that you don't have this code anymore?

Comment: there is no error message , maybe this part is skipped , I cannot debug it , or access all functions/macro called here

Comment: Run your compiler so as to obtain the preprocessed form.

Comment: Again, it doesn't help to know that you can't compile it. We simply can't help you without additional information. Go step by step through the error messages or your compiler. If you find an error related to the above macro, paste it here. Even if it is "company code", you should be able to find `foonew`.

Comment: `foonew` has to be available for you to look up somewhere. Look in the headers that your file includes. If `foonew` does not appear anywhere, then foo must not be called. Run a search for foonew on your entire codebase and see what you get, and let us know.

Comment: I cannot access foonew , If you have an explanation assuming it either a function or macro ,please give one

Comment: If you cannot access `foonew`, then `foo` must not be called anywhere in your codebase. If `foo` is being called somewhere, then you you are wrong and you do have access to `foonew`.

Comment: Maybe the compiler is proprietary and compiles a proprietary variant or extension of C. Or perhaps that code piece is not compiled, because of `#if 0` (or other preprocessing) which ignores it.

Comment: Why the downvotes here ? Question is not unreasonable compared to some of the stuff here.

Answer (score 1):

The semicolon works as a preprocessing token, just like `a` and `b`. It can be used as a parameter to another macro.

For example

```
#define foonew(x,y,z)   (x + y) z

#define foo(a,b)    foonew(a,b, ;)

int main()
{
   int one = 1;
   int two = 2;

   int three = foo(one, two)   // no semicolon here!

    return three;

}
```

Comment: What advantage does this offer ?

Comment: No advantage really, just an example of the crazy things you can do with macros.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
 #define foo(a,b) foonew(a,b)
```

try this.

A macro argument can be empty (consisting of zero preprocessing tokens). For example,

```
 #define SUM(a,b,c) a + b + c
  SUM(1,,3)  /* No error message.
```

1 is substituted for a, 3 is substituted for c. */
If the identifier list does not end with an ellipsis, the number of arguments in a macro invocation must be the same as the number of parameters in the corresponding macro definition. During parameter substitution, any arguments remaining after all specified arguments have been substituted (including any separating commas) are combined into one argument called the variable argument